# how to disable 3d secure from billsby

Tags: api

We have billsby subscription with stripe,

Now all working fine with test mode but when live mode and try to create subscription with card then it failed with card verification failed error.

So how to disable 3d secure from billsby?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should ask billsby?

Comment: yes true i have asked, but no response.